# User Scrolling Issue

Tags: website-design, scrolling

I have a site where I

am thinking about putting an ajax "click for more results" similar to twitter, etc. But each of my results is displayed with A, B, C next to the result. I'm wondering what I should do when user click for more results. Should I keep going and just go all the way to AAB, AAC, AAD or should I restart the ordering and go A, B, C again? Which would be easier for the user?

I hope this question is clear. Thanks for any help.

**edit: so what I mean is like this:
(these are like what the listings would be)**

A. This is listing 1

---

B. This is listing 2.

---

C. This is listing 3

---

D. This is listing 4.

**On the "click for more" it could either restart the**

A. This is listing 1

---

B. This is listing 2.

---

C. This is listing 3

---

D. This is listing 4.

**or it could keep going until it was like**

Aa. This is listing 27

---

Ab. This is listing 28.

---

Ac. This is listing 29

---

Ad. This is listing 30.

To give you more information on why I need these references, let me explain. I have a business directory. The reason I have need for these letters on the side is that I also have a map with icons that match to each of the listings.

Comment: Could you clarify the question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by A, B, C, AAB, AAC, and AAD. Could you please explain further? This may very well be an interesting question but I doublt you will get good answers since the question is totally unclear.

Comment: A wireframe or sketch would be great. This is some sort of recursive display of similar items, with a second pane showing related items to the first item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something you really need to do then try combining page number *and* result. Using multiple letters AAC, etc, is not a good system and just serves to confuse.

1-A

1-B

1-C

--

2-A

2-B

2-C

--

3-A

...

Answer (score 0):

A,B,C... is just not well suited for infinitely long lists.

1,2,3... isn't much use either for alignment reasons.

My question is: how useful is it to give each result a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this thread.  A question I asked a while back.  I think it ight be useful to you.

[How to combine search results from multiple sources onto the same results page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/how-to-combine-search-results-from-multiple-sources-onto-the-same-results-page)